# Other meaning of 可愛い?

Tags: definitions

As far as I know, 可愛い【かわいい】 means cute. However, I recently read on the internet that it has another meaning akin to "overvalue yourself"

For example

> 結構【けっこう】　皆【みんな】　自分【じぶん】の身【み】が可愛い【かわいい】のさ

or

> そんなに自分【じぶん】が可愛い【かわいい】のかよ?

Both contexts I've seen, the word is used in the context of a character saving his own skin over another person. Could some explain this use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [entry from the goo dictionary](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E5%8F%AF%E6%84%9B%E3%81%84_%28%E3%81%8B%E3%82%8F%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%29/#jn-46843) lists 4 meanings for 可愛い, of which the first 3 translates to "cute". The fourth meaning:

> **4** かわいそうだ。ふびんである。

sort of means "someone that is treated unfairly; someone you feel sorry for".

But specifically used after 自分, 自分の身, 我が身, 己 or any other equivalent of "self", it has the [following meaning](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E6%88%91%E3%81%8C%E8%BA%AB%E5%8F%AF%E6%84%9B%E3%81%95/):

> **我が身可愛さ（わがみかわいさ）**
> 何をおいても自分の身を守ろうとするさまをいう語。保身第一。

"An expression that means protecting oneself above anything."